Access multiple left join query won't save gets syntax error
I'm trying to run a query with multiple left joins. I understand that MS Access has additional parameters requiring () around the joins, otherwise I get a syntax error "Missing Operator" error, however I'm using sub-queries which adds even more complexity. I can't figure out the syntax. I have even tried chatgpt and copilot and both say my query is good. Can someone help? Here is my code:
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        tblTasks.ID, 
        tblTasks.csr_number, 
        tblTasks.title, 
        tblTasks.engineer, 
        tblTasks.poc, 
        tblTasks.customer, 
        tblTasks.complete, 
        tblTasks.status, 
        tblTasks.base_end 
    FROM tblTasks 
    WHERE 
        tblTasks.csr_number IS NOT NULL 
        AND tblTasks.complete < 1 
        AND tblTasks.status <> 'On hold' 
) AS tasks 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM tblNotes AS n1 
    WHERE n1.note_date = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(n2.note_date) 
        FROM tblNotes as n2 
        WHERE n2.note_id = n1.note_id
    )
) AS notes ON tasks.ID = notes.note_id 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        tblAttach.task_id,
        tblAttach.attach_name
    FROM tblAttach
    WHERE attach_name LIKE '\\*'
) AS tAttach ON tasks.ID = tAttach.task_id;


Search Access multiple join, and you'll find what's needed. (Extra sets of parentheses.)

Use query builder. Build the inner queries and save as query objects. Then reference them to build outer query. Now view the SQL to see correct syntax. Then if you want all-in-one, copy/paste the inner query SQL into the outer query with AS alias. Don't forget to include pair of parens around the nested SQL. Delete individual inner query objects.

@topsail, doesn't matter - INNER, LEFT, RIGHT - Access requires extra parens and fails without.

Access prefers parentheses around the query.
Try add ( and ):
SELECT * 
FROM 
( <-this
  (
    SELECT tblTasks.ID,tblTasks.csr_number, tblTasks.title, 
        tblTasks.engineer, tblTasks.poc, tblTasks.customer, 
        tblTasks.complete, tblTasks.status, tblTasks.base_end 
    FROM tblTasks 
    WHERE 
        tblTasks.csr_number IS NOT NULL 
        AND tblTasks.complete < 1 
        AND tblTasks.status <> 'On hold' 
  ) AS tasks 
  LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tblNotes AS n1 
    WHERE n1.note_date = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(n2.note_date) 
        FROM tblNotes as n2 
        WHERE n2.note_id = n1.note_id
    )
  ) AS notes ON tasks.ID = notes.note_id 
)<-and this

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT tblAttach.task_id, tblAttach.attach_name 
    FROM tblAttach
    WHERE attach_name LIKE '\\*'
) AS tAttach ON tasks.ID = tAttach.task_id;

